# Why won't a new line be created in this string? is it too long?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a simple question asking program that it asks all the questions in the array named tbl. For some reason, it works when i ask question 1 and question 3 but when I add a third answer, it becomes weird, no errors, just doesn't make a new line. Please help.

```py
tbl = [
["first?",["yes", "no", "no"],0],
["second?",["no", "no", "no", "no" "yes"],4],
["third?",["no", "no", "no","yes"],3],
]
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

def ask_question(q):
    s1 = "\n"
    amt = 0
    for x in q[1]:
        s1 = (s1 + letters[amt] +". " + x + "\n")
        amt = amt + 1
    string = (q[0] + s1)
    print(string)

ask_question(tbl[1])
```

Output:

```
second?
a. no
b. no
c. no
d. noyes
```

Comment: Typo, missing comma: `["second?",["no", "no", "no", "no", "yes"],4],`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is this line: `["second?",["no", "no", "no", "no" "yes"],4],`
it should be `["second?",["no", "no", "no", "no","yes"],4],`
(You are missing a comma)

Comment: Oh, lol thank you. :)

Comment: If the original question can be solved just by fixing a small typo, then don't answer, just vote to close and move on to the next question.

Comment: Not sure how to do that I'm new to this website.

Comment: @Plieax click the up arrow

Comment: @Plieax He was telling me to just comment instead of answer